# The module has not been deployed

Tags: spring, tomcat, jakarta-ee, netbeans-7

> i'm working on JEE application on netBeans with Tomcat. when adding "applicationContext.xml" ,
>   then build and run i have this error:

The module has not been deployed. See the server log for details.   at org.netbeans.modules.j2ee.deployment.devmodules.api.Deployment.deploy(Deployment.java:238)   at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.performDeploy(ExecutionChecker.java:205)    at org.netbeans.modules.maven.j2ee.ExecutionChecker.executionResult(ExecutionChecker.java:123)  at org.netbeans.modules.maven.execute.MavenCommandLineExecutor.run(MavenCommandLineExecutor.java:235)   at org.netbeans.core.execution.RunClassThread.run(RunClassThread.java:153)

Comment: The module has not been deployed. **See the server log for details**. at ...

Comment: so you want to deploy a JEE app to a servlet container?

Answer (score 0):

I just change the value debugmode from false to true.